# Is it possible to have an abstract template that forces exclusive constructors for derived?

Tags: c#, templates, constructor, abstract-class, factory-pattern

To shorten the question it is a bit simplified.
The main point is to force exclusive calling all base constructors from derived and prohibit all other constructors.

Forcing one exclusive constructor by abstract template works:

```
public abstract class AbstractTemplatePattern
{
    protected AbstractTemplatePattern(Foo foo)
    {
        // do the same work for every derived class
    }
}

class DerivedTemplatePattern : AbstractTemplatePattern
{
    // exclusive constructor forced by template (no others allowed)
    public DerivedTemplatePattern(Foo foo) : base(foo) { }

    // possible too, force calling the base contructor is the main thing here!
    public DerivedTemplatePattern() : base(new Foo()) { }
    public DerivedTemplatePattern(Bar bar) : base(new Foo()) { }

    // not allowed constructor examples
    public DerivedTemplatePattern() { }
    public DerivedTemplatePattern(Bar bar) { }
}
```

The obvious extension to n exclusive constructors will not force to have n exclusive constructors in derived class, it only forces one of them:

```
public abstract class AbstractTemplatePattern
{
    protected AbstractTemplatePattern(Foo foo)
    {
        // do the same work for every derived class
    }

    protected AbstractTemplatePattern(Bar bar)
    {
        // do the same work for every derived class
    }
}

class DerivedTemplatePattern : AbstractTemplatePattern
{
    // no error, but this should not be allowed, as the template gives two constructors
    public DerivedTemplatePattern(Foo foo) : base(foo) { }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with an abstract template?

If it helps: implementing a factory pattern would be an option.

Comment: From where did you get the idea that you cannot define more constructors? It works as long as you provide the required parameters to the parent: https://dotnetfiddle.net/36Uw5n

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto You are right, but it does not pollute the intention: calling the base constructor is meant what should be forced by template. In this point the wording is not as accurate as it could be. But your fiddle gives me some more ideas - have to think about it :D